# Impolite to new users

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that new users, who often ask rather poor questions, are often downvoted with no guidance at all, or are given harsh criticism without being welcomed into the community.  The purpose of the First Posts review queue is to allow corrective suggestions, so downvotes without guidance are simply inappropriate.

Shouldn't some kind of welcome also be provided?  Everyone is coming because they want an answer to a question, and when folks are first beginning on the site, they are often very sensitive to their score.  In the long run, we win as a community if we can bring people *into the fold* while also teaching them how to ask questions well.

Comment: Could you give some examples (links) of what you consider an impolite welcome?

Comment: Unfortunately, we get a lot of bad questions that are very lazy — do-my-homework-for-me. I have a hard time justifying that it would be inappropriate to respond with just as much effort — vote to close, downvote and move on.

Comment: We have a publicly available help center, which justifies many actions towards the not-so-great questions flow. Downvote indicated that question is not particularly helpful, close reason is visible. And lastly the eagerness to guide not policy compatible users fades with amount of reviewed posts. Sometimes users get hostile after learning that doing their homework is not our obligation. If only there were strong evidence that it works probably more people would spare time to guide them, but it is mostly homework-and-run.

Comment: “Every day, good-hearted people come to these sites and run into serious problems. And then you come here or to another meta site (…)... And no one cares.” [Show your work: one simple trick to make meta effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296339/show-your-work-one-simple-trick-to-make-meta-effective)

Comment: Haha, I saw that yesterday, several hours after I wrote this post.  I thought about going back to revise, but the prospect of hunting through a bunch of messages after-the-fact just caused me to wither up and die ever so slightly inside.  I'd rather just delete this whole question, TBH.

Comment: I think there's a difference between a poor question and a problem dump. A problem dump shows no effort: the asker has not bothered at all to find out what kind of questions are appropriate, and is generally not interested in being any part of the community. In this case, all the asker wants is someone to do his/her homework. I am typically quite harsh with such askers, and I often downvote and/or vote to close without any comments. I would find it too frustrating, time-consuming and pointless to leave comments, because I don't believe the asker will bother to read those either.

Comment: In contrast, I think we have had several cases of "poor questions", that have been edited by the community to be up to standards and answered. But I am also not saying we couldn't do a better job at that too.

Comment: What Juho and Gilles said! Also there are new users who ask at meta, show the thinking process or start question from apologies that they are not sure whether the question is ok or this is proper stack. They do read help center or response to comments blazingly fast, because they care. Even if they do not stick around, still they contribute polished question. So hey, it is possible and I haven't witnessed any of them treated anything less than good and welcomed. Mayhap the help tour should be bigger and obligatory? The question locked until they look at similar ones proposed by system?

Comment: Agreed. Posting a problem dump is impolite in itself.